# AngularJS $http get to ASP.NET Web Api with object in parameters

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to get filtered data from server using a filtering object I pass to the server side. I have managed to get this working with a post:

angular:

```
var filter: { includeDeleted: true, foo: bar };
$http({ method: 'post', url: 'api/stuff', data: filter });
```

web api:

```
public IEnumerable<StuffResponse> Post([FromBody]Filter filter)
{
    return GetData(filter);
}
```

But i don't want to use a post for this, I want to use a get. But this does not work:

angular

```
$http({ method: 'get', url: 'api/stuff', params: filter });
```

web api

```
public IEnumerable<StuffResponse> Get([FromUri]Filter filter)
{
    return GetData(filter);
}
```

Also tried specifying params: { filter: filter }.
If i try [FromBody] or nothing, filter is null. With the FromUri i get an object at least - but with no data.  Any ideas how to solve this, without creating input parameters for all filter properties?

Comment: I think you can't  pass data to get method's

Comment: simply remove [FromUrl] attribute, and make sure in Filter class, includeDeleted as a public property, it should work.

Comment: Standard media type formatter would not do this. Custom media type formatter is required. See here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/701182/A-Custom-Model-Binder-for-Passing-Complex-Objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `HTTP GET` request can't contain data to be posted to the server. What you want is to a a query string to the request. Fortunately `angular.http` provides an option for it `params`.

See : http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get

Comment: As you see in the example with 'get', I am using 'params'. And I can see the filter object is translated to URL parameters in the request - but the server can't deserialize it to the Filter object

Comment: Filter is a class name, So you can't do this, you can't pass class in a query string, so you need to change the class to string,int,float...

Comment: Vil's answer provides a cleaner solution imo

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can send data with **Get** method by sending them with `params`  option

```
var data ={
  property1:value1,
  property2:value2,
  property3:value3
};

$http({ method: 'GET', url: 'api/controller/method', params: data });
```

and you will receive this by using `[FromUri]` in your api controller method

```
public IEnumerable<StuffResponse> Get([FromUri]Filter filter)
{
    return GetData(filter);
}
```

and the request url will be like this

```
http://localhost/api/controller/method?property1=value1&property2=value2&property3=value3
```

Answer (score 4):

Solved it this way:

Angular:

```
$http({
       url: '/myApiUrl',
       method: 'GET',
       params: { param1: angular.toJson(myComplexObject, false) }
      })
```

C#:

```
[HttpGet]
public string Get(string param1)
{
     Type1 obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Type1>(param1);
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can send object with **Get or Post** method  .

**Script**

```
//1.
var order = {
     CustomerName: 'MS' };
//2.
var itemDetails = [
     { ItemName: 'Desktop', Quantity: 10, UnitPrice: 45000 },
     { ItemName: 'Laptop', Quantity: 30, UnitPrice: 80000 },
     { ItemName: 'Router', Quantity: 50, UnitPrice: 5000 }
];
//3.
$.ajax({
     url: 'http://localhost:32261/api/HotelBooking/List',
     type: 'POST',
     data: {order: order,itemDetails: itemDetails},
     ContentType: 'application/json;utf-8',
     datatype: 'json'
    }).done(function (resp) {
        alert("Successful " + resp);
    }).error(function (err) {
        alert("Error " + err.status);});
```

**API Code**

```
[Route("api/HotelBooking/List")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult PostList(JObject objData)
{  List<ItemDetails > lstItemDetails = new List<ItemDetails >();
   dynamic jsonData = objData;
   JObject orderJson = jsonData.itemDetails;
   return Ok();}
```

Comment: that's a POST. Does it work with a get? Plus it's not angular JS.